# create checkbox inside optioncollections tag in struts

Tags: html, checkbox, struts, struts1

i wanna create a checkbox inside a optioncollections tag in struts 1.3. I tried this code but it's not working:-

```
<html:optionsCollection name="FileUploadForm" property="userSList" label="description" value="userName" >

             <html:checkbox property="description" />
 </html:optionsCollection>
```